# xcode storyboard - ibtoold unarchiving exception

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, uistoryboard

the exception is;

```
CompileStoryboard Catwall/en.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboard
cd /Users/guvenozyurt/Desktop/git/catwall_ios
setenv IBSC_MINIMUM_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION 5.1
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
setenv XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/guvenozyurt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Catwall-ghvlotdrbpzsfveimvmoxitsgpod/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Catwall.app/en.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboardc /Users/guvenozyurt/Desktop/git/catwall_ios/Catwall/en.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboard --sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk


2013-03-07 17:14:26.187 ibtoold[34122:707] Exception raised while unarchiving document objects - *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil/* com.apple.ibtool.errors *//Users/guvenozyurt/Desktop/git/catwall_ios/Catwall/en.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboard: error: The document "MainStoryboard.storyboard" could not be opened. The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.InterfaceBuilder error -1.)    Recovery Suggestion: Check the console log for additional informat..
```

Recently, I delete an xib file and make the whole drawing on controller side. Then merged the code from git, resolved conflicts (quite carefully, 3 times reset and did it again..)

I checked simulators. build target version, tried to change "copy bundle resources" order not so deeply . No ! It is still failed. .

ibtoold is not opensource of course, and i do know what is going on there. .

i'm stucked and need help! Thanks..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just ran into this when trying to open a project - with custom fonts set in a Storyboard - on another computer.

Turns out, the custom fonts needed to be added to that computers Font Book.

Of course, doing it in code works too.

Answer (score 15):

There can be multiple reasons for this error. I got this error after merging storyboards using git.
My storyboard also had custom font and I installed them after reading this thread (+1 for that), even after that also I was getting the same error.
Then I searched all the places where I got conflict and finally found that one of the `segue` present in `inferredMetricsTieBreakers` was not used anywhere in the storyboard. I removed that and restarted XCode and tada everything back in place.

So the bottom line is that thoroughly visit all the places with conflicts, you should be able to solve most merge issues.

-anoop

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this. +500 rep bounty coming your way.

Comment: @AaronBrager glad that it helped, these kind of issues kill a lot of time and you will go mad

Comment: Thanks a lot. Saved my life on this!

Comment: You're a genius.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue, and found that it was because I was referencing a font in the Storyboard file that I'd included in the iOS app.

For some reason, once I set the font in code rather than in the Storyboard it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was storyboard. I revert git merge on storyboard, so it is able to open on xcode, then remove references manually not by git. Then the error is gone. Magical IOS world..